# Inputting String and Convert to ASCII

Tags: java, ascii

My problem is that when i input "b" it converts correctly but when i input other letters it just displaying the conversion of "b"

```
char ch = 'b';
int ascii = ch;
int castAscii = (int) ch;
DisplayText.setText(UserInput.getText() + " = " + castAscii);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Please show what you are expecting in `DisplayText`, and what you get instead (as well as what you expect/get for "other letters", showing the "other letters")

Comment: In my variable i declared it "b" that's why it just showing the conversion of "b"
how do i change it to convert what i input instead of the "b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you only convert the character `b` to it's ascii value and not the actual user input. Assuming that `UserInput.getText()` returns the user defined character as character and not string:

```
int castAscii = (int) UserInput.getText();
DisplayText.setText(UserInput.getText() + " = " + castAscii);
```

In case `UserInput.getText()` returns a string, you can convert it into a character array and then iterate through it to combine the output.

```
String userInput = UserInput.getText();
String output = userInput + "=";
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
    int castAscii = (int) userInput.toCharArray()[i];
    output  += castAscii;
    if (i < userInput.length()) {
        output += ",";
    } 
}
DisplayText.setText(output);
```

Using a framework like apache commons-lang would make for a more elegant solution, but this will work.

Comment: It says String cannot be converted to int

Comment: why when i tried typing words it just only take the first letter?

Comment: That is because on line 3 you take the first character out of the array. If you want to have all, you would probably need a for loop and a different way to present the output as there will be multiple integers.

Comment: can you help me about the loop?

Comment: hurray!! got it sir thank you so much thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

you set the ch='b'.so always you convert the "b" and ignore the input.

you must set the `ch` to what the user entered.

as I mentioned in comments,this is an example code to clarify the process.

```
    String s = "hello";
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(chars[i]);
        int ascii = (int) chars[i];
        System.out.println(ascii);
    }
```

you can write scanner.nextline() instead of "hello" next to String `s` to get the string from the user.

Comment: i tried inputing my variable in input but it shows errors

Comment: use `int ascii = (int)ch;` instead of `int ascii = ch;` that you have written here

Comment: did my answer change anything in your idea that it was helpful to you?

Comment: i still got an error it just makes my input to change to string then after that it shown errors

Comment: note that you can't convert an string to an integer by cast it.you must convert it to an charArray and by a for loop you can access to each character in that string and then you can cast each element of the array to int by casting because each element is a char not String

Comment: It says String cannot be converted to int

Comment: as I consider in my last comment the string can not cast to an integer.you must convert the whole string to char array and then convert each element of the array to int to obtain their ascii code

Comment: if it is still unclear tell me to write a code for you in my answer to clarify what I have said

Comment: can you modified my code and make it when i input words it converts all the letter into ascii?

Comment: i write a code in my main answer.run it once for yourself to clarify the process.